# Run a URL without leaving the page using AJAX / Laravel Project

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I currently use the following code so when the user clicks the play button in the picture below, it runs the route that processes that lines function.

```
$(function () {
    $('#g{{$job->id}}').on('click', function () {
        var Status = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('/jobs/run', $job->calltoken) }}'
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

I loop through all the rows in the table and create this line of code for each one at the bottom of my view.

My problem now is that I have a user that has over 1000 rows and its hit and miss if it works and the page is slow and over 30k line of html.

Is there a simpler way I can do it where it only requires one function for all rather than a function for each?

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome..

Comment: Use lazy loading in view

Comment: Are you doing non-index query?

Comment: I think you don't have pagination, then add paginate system

Comment: I have paging on my data-tables, going to look at doing it server side to take strain off the browser.

If I can cut the function down to one function for all, then it reduces lines of code by 26000.